# Neo4jClient with keylines

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, neo4j, neo4jclient

**Introduction:**
I am a newbie to Neo4jClient so forgive me if i ask something that has been asked before. But i have been stuck on this forever.

**What i Am trying to do:** 
I am trying to connect Neo4j with Keylines using .NET.

**Cause:** 
First, i used Neo4j's REST with Jquery AJAX to do Return (*) which returned everything including data and URI's of self, start, end, all_Relationships etc.

```
data: Object
end: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/93"
extensions: Object
metadata: Object
properties: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/4019/properties"
property: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/4019/properties/{key}"
self: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/4019"
start: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/6"
type: "SENT"
```

Hence i was able to use self as a ID for keylines Node and start and end URI's as Keyline's Link id1 and id2.

```
function queryNeo4j(query) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "query": query, "params": {} }),
            success: afterQueryNeo4j
        });
    };
function afterQueryNeo4j(json) {
         console.log(json); // returned data from ajax call
        makeNodes(json);
        makeLinks(json);
        //console.log(items);
        createKeylines(items);
    };
 // populates global var itmes with nodes
    function makeNodes(param) {
        for (i = 0; i < param.data.length ; i++) {
            for (j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++) {
                var node = {
                    type: 'node',
                    id: param.data[i][j].self,
                    dt: stringToDateConverter(String(param.data[i][1].data.yyyyMMdd)),
                    b: 'rgb(100,255,0)',
                    c: 'rgb(0,0,255)',
                    t: param.data[i][j].data.name,
                    subject: param.data[i][j].data.subject
                };
                items.push(node);
            }
        }
    };

    // populates global var itmes with nodes
    function makeLinks(json) {
        for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
            var link = {
                type: 'link',
                id: json.data[i][2].self,
                id1: json.data[i][2].start,
                id2: json.data[i][2].end,
                t: json.data[i][2].metadata.type,
                w: 2,
                c: 'rgb(0,0,255)'
            }
            items.push(link);
        }
    }
```

Using this technique i was successfully able to plot keylines graph and timebar using only client side Javascript.
but problem Arose when i published this on IIS, it gave me Cross-Domain error which means i had to call Neo4j from server code (C#) and feed it to client side HTML/JS. That's when i found out about Neo4jClient.

**Done so Far:** 
I am Successfully able to read data from Neo4j in my C# code using

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int dob { get; set; }
}
var query = client.cypher
.match(("person:Person"))
.return(person => person.As<Person>());
var result = query.results;
foreach (var i in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("people name is:"+i.name);
            }
```

**Problem:** 
Now, i can read only data based on my Cypher Query but can't read other stuff like id, self, start, end URI's and relationships which i need for my UI.

Is there a way to get the Return (*) and all the other meta data using neo4jclient? Any code will help.
Should i stick to Client side ajax call by resolving cross reference errors using JSONP or CORS since it was much easier but i am afraid that it might give me some problems down the line as it is not the proper way to do it?

I can't seem to find any proper documentation for Neo4jClient. 
There are so many options i see for return in Intellisense but dont't know how i can use them.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Googling for "neo4jclient documentation" : https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `return` to be:

```
.Return(person => person.As<Node<Person>>());
```

Which will return a wrapper around the `Data` containing all the node goodness, that should get you there.